# How to escape from visualMap control in echarts

Tags: heatmap, echarts

I am using heatmap in echarts to show temperature change.
I want to show unique color like grey when the value of the item is zero or undefined.

But it is showing the colored grid.
I found a solution to give same zero value for both zero and undefined and set the same color.

but their color is being controlled by visual map.
ECHARTS doc says "Mark as `visual map: false`, then this item does not control by visual map any more". but this is very unclear.
Where can I set this property "visual map"?
in data of series?

Please help me if you have experience with this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it needs to be in series property.

```
series: [{
  name: 'Punch Card',
  typs: 'heatmap',
  data: [{
    value: [0,0,5],
    }, {
    value: [1,0,0],
    visualMap: false, // this will be escaped from visualMap control
  }],
  itemStyle: {
    normal: {
      color: 'rgb(0,255,0)', // this will be color of uncontrolled item
    },
  },
}]
```